# Получить класс с помощью фабрики

Tags: java, функции, абстрактная-фабрика

Всем привет. Мне нужно в одном из методов класса получить экземпляр другого класса в зависимости от значения переменной.Сделал так.

**Интерфейс**

```
public interface Geography {
 void geo();
}
```

**class GeographyFactory**

```
public class GeographyFactory{
 private static Context mCtx;
 public GeographyFactory(Context ctx) {
  mCtx = ctx;
 }


 public <GTypes> Geography getGeography(GTypes type){
         Geography toReturn = null;
  if (COUNTRY.equals(type)) {
   toReturn = new CountryRequest(mCtx);
  }

         return toReturn;
 }

 }
```

**class CountryRequest**

```
public class CountryRequest implements Geography {

 private static Context mCtx;
 public CountryRequest(Context ctx) {
  mCtx =ctx;
 }

 @Override
 public void geo() {
  ApiCallCountry apiCallCountry = new ApiCallCountry(mCtx);
 }
}
```

**class SearchGeo**

```
public class SearchGeo{
 public SearchGeo(Context ctx,String where, View aut, TextView selectedText){
..
}
private void makeApiCall(Context ctx, String text, String where) {

GeographyFactory geographyFactory = new GeographyFactory(ctx);

}
}
```

Как мне в makeApiCall() получить экземпляр new ApiCallCountry(mCtx) используя фабрику?

Comment: Если вы хотите экземпляр `ApiCallCountry`, то зачем сделали фабрику для `Geography`? Не понятно чего вы хотите добиться  - опишите подробнее схему задумки.

Comment: Да суть не в этом, какой там класс. Это просто пример на этом классе. Классов будет несколько. Интересует сам механизм передачи экземпляра класса.

Comment: Так а при чём тут фабрика? Суть фабрики в том, чтобы выдавать конкретные экземпляры класса/интерфейса, в зависимости от аргументов и состояния. А что вы дальше делаете с полученным объектом к фабрике не имеет отношения. Вы создали фабрику, получаете из неё обеъкт: `Geography g = geographyFactory.getGeography(type)`. Если вы хотите что-то получить из этого объекта - объявите в `Geography` метод, который вам выдаст что нужно, а-ля `ApiCallCountry  getApiCallCountry();`. И реализуйте его в `CountryRequest`.

Comment: Так вроде и вопрос стоит так же. Получить экземпляр класса в зависимости от значения переменной). У меня в **class SearchGeo** приходит переменная **String where** и в зависимости от её значения мне нужно получить соответственный класс и в методе **private void makeApiCall()** я буду обращаться к методу полученного класса. И я не понимаю как я могу в **Geography** обратиться к методу этого класса? Я могу к нему обратиться только из класса **class SearchGeo**, так как там все нужные параметры.